# I get an error ( 500-internal server error ) when posting with Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

No matter what I do, I couldn't fix the problem, what do you think could be the problem ?

This is my model class :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long id;
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    public String first_name;
    
    @Column (name="last_name")
    public String last_name;
}
```

This is my repository :

```
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<User , Long>{

    // All C.R.U.D database methods
    
    @Query (value = "Select * from users where first_name=:name" , nativeQuery=true)
    public List<User> getUser (String name);
}
```

Finally , This is my controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api/v1/user")
public class CommentController {
    
    @Autowired
    CommentRepository repository ;
    
    @GetMapping(path="/list")
    public List<User> users() {
        
        return repository.findAll();
    }  
    
    @GetMapping(path="/person")
    public List<User> user(@RequestParam String name ) {
        
        return repository.getUser(name);
    } 
    
    @PostMapping(path="/save")
    public void save(@RequestBody User user ) {
        
        repository.save ( user );
    } 
    
    @DeleteMapping(path="/delete")
    public void delete(@RequestBody User user ) {
        
        repository.delete( user );
    } 
}
```

Logcat :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

According to this output, I should not give an empty value to the id value, but the id variable is automatically assigned on mysql.

I know I'm bad at giving model and class names I'm just doing a trial run :)

Comment: Edit question to add the exception message, complete stacktrace, the request you send when the exception happens.

Comment: @Chaosfire I don't understand , can you give some more detailed information please ?

Comment: post the error stack trace printed in logs. You can start debugging by the method which is giving exception,"save","list","delete" or"person". surround it with try catch to understand reason. Next you could add debug point there and try catching issue with your debugger

Comment: @Kirion 500 internal serve error is the generic response the server generates when unhandled exception occurs. On the server(or in IDE, however you ar running ptoject) you will have the exception message and stacktrace for that exception, we need those to help. You say that you are `posting`, which makes me believe you are executing a POST request, when exception occurs. We need the body of the request as well.

Comment: @Chaosfire I corrected my question and added the logcat section to the bottom :)

Comment: @Kirion A shot in the dark, but you can change the id field in `User` to `Long`. `long` has a default value of `0`, not `null` compared to `Long` and this might be breaking the generated query.

Comment: @Chaosfire Thank you very much, I got it done, I just needed to set the primary key of the table to auto increment in mysql server : )

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates error in type of id. Either you pass it in request or set to following to prevent it:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

instead of following:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```